# Is it possible to use a custom Java trust store for Jenkin's Artifactory Plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, artifactory

Can I specify a custom Java trust store for the Jenkins Artifactory plugin? I'm really looking for a place to add Java options, `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=...` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=...`.

I was able to do this successfully with the SonarQube by adding an environment variable:

```
SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/data/.../mycompanycerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```

But downstream, I'm seeing this error when publishing to Artifactory:

```
org.jfrog.build.util.VersionException: Error occurred while requesting version information: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Our company is setting up a Continuous Integration environment with Jenkins, BitBucket, Artifactory, and SonarQube. Each server is connected to our domain and there is one company ca certificate for the whole company domain: *.mycompany.lcl

While searching on the internet, most people recommended to add the needed certificate to the default Java key store. The infrastructure team won't let me do this as they have a certain location that they put the trust store on all our servers. Then they know where to go if there are any updates/additions to that trust store.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/issues/97), feel free to :+1: it.